# Clustering using Mathematica

Tags: cluster-analysis

I've got a two column table (Fields, Methods) and I'd like to find which Methods relates to many Fields. 
Can I accomplish this task using Mathematica?

This are the sample data.
https://jpst.it/L6I5

Comment: Use `Tally[]`..

Comment: @Feyre: mmm... I look for something more similart to data mining I guess.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not fully sure what you're asking for, but do these ideas help?

```
data = Import["https://justpaste.it/wiaz", "Data"][[1, 2]];

#[[1, 2]] -> #[[All, 1]] & /@ GatherBy[data, Last]

{
  "DrawOdds_Main(PrintPageEventArgs,Boolean)" -> 
    {"_drawMarkets", "_lastPrintedSport", "_noPrint", "_pageHeight", 
    "_pageIndex", "_pageWidth", "_personalTemplate", 
    "_previousPrintingStatus", "_printingStatus", "_printRows", 
    "_rowIndex", "_sportIndex", "_sports", "_tournamentPrintingData", 
    "Settings"}, 
  "AltreCondizioniDiStampa(List,List,Int32,PrintRowOrder)" -> 
    {"_rowIndex", "_tournamentPrintingData"}, 
  "Init(List,Dictionary<AggregateSport,List>)" -> 
    {"Settings", "_printDialog", "_printDocument", 
    "_personalTemplate", "_sports", "_printRows"}, 
  "InitPrinter()" -> 
    {"_printDocument", "_pageHeight", "_pageWidth", "_personalTemplate"}, 
  "InizializzaMisureTemplate(PersonalTemplate)" -> 
    {"_personalTemplate"}, 
  "Print(Int32)" -> 
    {"_printDialog", "_printDocument", "_printerSettingsToPage", "_printerSettingsFromPage"}, 
  "PrintPreview()" -> 
    {"_printerSettingsToPage", "_printerSettingsFromPage", "_pageIndex", 
    "_pageHeight", "_pageWidth"}, 
  "Reset()" -> 
    {"_rowIndex", "_sportIndex", "_noPrint", "_drawMarkets"}, 
  "UpdateNextPageParam(PrintPageEventArgs)" -> 
    {"_printerSettingsToPage", "_printerSettingsFromPage", 
    "_pageIndex", "_noPrint", "_drawMarkets"}, 
  "UpdatePrintingStatus(AggregateSport,List)" -> 
    {"_rowIndex", "_tournamentPrintingData", "_lastPrintedSport", 
    "_printingStatus", "_previousPrintingStatus"}
}
```

Alternatively you could use `GroupBy[data, Last]`.

Or maybe you're wanting to visualize it as a network?

```
Graph[DirectedEdge @@@ Reverse /@ data, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Tooltip]]
```

[image]